# Getting a wrong output when printing a dynamic array

Tags: c

I'm trying to input an array length from user, and the output the numbers..

I get only "1", "1", "1" as output when n = 3, and num's values are integers.

```
int main()
{
    int *arr1, n,num = 0,*p;
    printf("Please enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    arr1 = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (arr1 == NULL)
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
    else  printf("Array was allocated!\n" );
    for (p = arr1; p < arr1 + n; p++)
    {
        *p = scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("%d ", *p);
    }

    free(arr1);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You use `scanf` correctly one time, why not the second?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Damn good question.

Comment: For future reference, when posting a question regarding unexpected output, besides telling us the actual output also include the *expected* output, as well as the input. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf` returns the **number of matches**. `num` contains the entered integer.
From [`man scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> #### Return Value
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
>   and assigned [...]

Replace

```
*p = scanf("%d", &num);
```

with

```
scanf("%d", &num);
*p = num;
```

or simply<sup>1</sup>

```
scanf("%d", p);
```

to make it work properly.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to @JoachimPileborg!</sub>

Comment: Or simply `scanf("%d", p);`

Comment: Why  while (arr1 < arr1 +n)
 {
  scanf("%d", arr1);
 } doesn't work? @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS That code will work very well, if you want an infinite loop. You don't increase `an1` anywhere in the loop.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Still does not work. while (arr1 < arr1 + n)
 { 
  scanf("%d", arr1);
  arr1++;
 } It just continues asking for more input.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS because arr1 will ALWAYS be lesser than arr1 + n. Note that as arr1 increases, so does arr1 + n. You need a limit that is independent of arr1.